# Excel VBA Spellcheck Way Too Slow

Tags: excel, vba, spell-checking

I have a spreadsheet that lists all permutations of 5 columns of data into a single column of text (Column X aka 24) and my goal is to extract only actual words from that list into its own column (Column Y aka 25). The first part is not performed with VBA and happens almost instantaneously, but the spell check + extracting the actual words takes over an hour to complete (I've had to stop it it after 10 minutes and not even 10% of the way through). Is there a better way to do this?

My lists start on row 6 (n = 6) and Range("V3") is just the number of permutations (in this case, 83,521).

```
Sub Permute_and_Extract()

n = 6

Range("X7:X1000000").ClearContents
Range("Y6:Y1000000").ClearContents

Max = Range("V3") + 5
Range("X6").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("X6:X" & Max)

For i = 6 To Max
x = Application.CheckSpelling(Cells(i, 24).Text)
If x = True Then
Cells(n, 25) = Cells(i, 24)
n = n + 1
End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: What about removing impossible combinations? like "zxz**" etc

Comment: Load your data into a `Variant` array and loop over the array, rather than looping cell by cell.

Comment: Probably quicker to download a list of 5-letter words, load it to a dictionary, and use that for the checking (using an array as suggested by @BigBen).  You could (eg) get all 5-letter words from this list: https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/twl06/download/twl06.txt

Comment: Your main speed constraint is the CheckSpelling though, not the cell-by-cell access: 14.8 seconds to check 1000 values using a variant array, and only 0.2 seconds slower when going cell-by-cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from the comments above:

```vb
Sub Permute_and_Extract()

    Const RNG As String = "F1:F10000"
    Dim wlist As Object, t, c As Range, i As Long, arr, res
    Dim rngTest As Range
    
    Set rngTest = ActiveSheet.Range(RNG)
    
    t = Timer
    Set wlist = WordsList("C:\Temp\words.txt", 5)
    Debug.Print "loaded list", Timer - t
    Debug.Print wlist.Count, "words"
    
    'using an array approach...
    t = Timer
    arr = rngTest.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        res = wlist.exists(arr(i, 1))
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Array check", Timer - t
    
    'going cell-by-cell...
    t = Timer
    For Each c In rngTest.Cells
        res = wlist.exists(c.Value)
    Next c
    Debug.Print "Cell by cell", Timer - t
    
End Sub

'return a dictionary of words of length `wordLen` from file at `fPath`
Function WordsList(fPath As String, wordLen As Long) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, s As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare   'case-insensitive !!!
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile(fPath)
        Do While Not .AtEndOfStream
            s = .readline()
            If Len(s) = wordLen Then dict.Add s, True
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    Set WordsList = dict
End Function
```

Output:

```txt
loaded list    0.359375 
 8938         words
Array check    0.019 
Cell by cell   0.030
```

Comment: I tried it against a list of 759,375 5-letter permutations (15^5) and it took just under 10 seconds to complete using the dictionary & array method, so this should work. I have no idea what half of these functions do, but I will look them up over time I'm sure. I also disabled ScreenUpdating, EnableEvents, and turned Calculation to Manual before the method then reenabled them afterward to speed things up. I appreciate the help!